# fetch two category value in single array

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have 2 category 'cele_birth' and 'cele_anniv'.I want to get both values in single query in drupal 7.I have tried as below.I returns only cele_anniv result.how to fetch  both

```
$result = db_query('select response from {soap_service} where category = :category',array(':category' => 'cele_birth',':category' => 'cele_anniv'));
foreach($result as $record){
 $data = $record->response;
 $data = drupal_json_decode($data);
 print_r($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use OR condition in sql

```
$result = db_query('select response from {soap_service} where category = :category1 OR category = :category2',array(':category1' => 'cele_birth',':category2' => 'cele_anniv'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Siddharth answer is correct but not suitable when we have a lot of values to compare with. There is another work around, which will reduce writing the OR condition multiple times using the IN operator.

```
$result = db_query('select response from {soap_service} where category in (:category)',array(':category' => array('cele_birth', 'cele_anniv')));
```

More details on IN operator can be found here [SQL in operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)